# WSO2 API Message Mediation based on accept headers

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using WSO2 Api Manager as a proxy between a client and the server. The server sends XML responses that I successfully converted to a JSON response with a custom PayloadFactory message mediation. Problem that I now am facing is the following: How do I mediate based on the accept headers of a request?

When I have in the header of a request:
Accept application/json
I want to use my mediator to convert the response from the server to JSON, but when I have
Accept text/xml or application/xml
I don't want to use my mediator and just forward the response as is.

Edit:
Basicly the only thing a really need is to save my "Accept ... " header. I can forward it to the server, but the server doesn't do anything with it. Are there global variables or something that I can use per proxy request?

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Filter](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Filter%20Mediator) mediator or [Switch](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Switch%20Mediator) mediator to do a if-then-else kind of operations inside the insequence and implement your first requirement. You can get the header using [synapse xpath variables](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Synapse%20XPath%20Variables).
You can define a [custom sequence](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Adding%20Mediation%20Extensions) and add it to the api

for the second question, you can use [property](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Property%20Mediator) mediator to define values and use them later. set the 'Scope' parameter according to your need

Comment: Thank you, this indeed set me in the right direction. This was actually easier then I thought.

Now I am facing a new problem: The data dat is sent from the server can be an array of xml elements. How can I parse this to a json array? I am guessing that I need to use an iterator, but I am not sure how. If you again could point me in the right direction I would be gratefull.

Comment: I opened another question for this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35502509/wso2-api-payloadfactory-mediator-xml-array-to-json-array